# cURL Connection refused following MEAN tutorial

Tags: curl, mean

I've been following this [mean tutorial](https://thinkster.io/mean-stack-tutorial) and I'm in the part 'Testing the Initial Routes'

when I put on terminal

```
curl --data 'title=test&link=http://test.com' http://localhost:3000/posts
```

I get this error

```
curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 3000: Connection refused
```

I have OS X Yosemite 10.10.5

Firewall is down

```
curl -V
curl 7.43.0 (x86_64-apple-darwin14.0) libcurl/7.43.0 SecureTransport zlib/1.2.5
Protocols: dict file ftp ftps gopher http https imap imaps ldap ldaps pop3 pop3s rtsp smb smbs smtp smtps telnet tftp 
Features: AsynchDNS IPv6 Largefile GSS-API Kerberos SPNEGO NTLM NTLM_WB SSL libz UnixSockets
```

I've been looking around and tried using `-4` to force ipv4 and get same error

I've also found that I need to comment `fe80::1%lo0` from `/etc/hosts`but I don't even have it, this is how that file looks

```
##
# Host Database
#
# localhost is used to configure the loopback interface
# when the system is booting.  Do not change this entry.
##
127.0.0.1   localhost
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1             localhost
```

Also I've tried recommendations on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29552228/testing-rest-routes-with-curl-data-returns-404) but nothing.

This is my `app.js`:

```js
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

require('./models/Posts');
require('./models/Comments');

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/news');

var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var routes = require('./routes/index');
var users = require('./routes/users');

var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

// uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
//app.use(favicon(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'favicon.ico')));
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use('/', routes);
app.use('/users', users);

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  var err = new Error('Not Found');
  err.status = 404;
  next(err);
});

// error handlers

// development error handler
// will print stacktrace
if (app.get('env') === 'development') {
  app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
    res.status(err.status || 500);
    res.render('error', {
      message: err.message,
      error: err
    });
  });
}

// production error handler
// no stacktraces leaked to user
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error', {
    message: err.message,
    error: {}
  });
});

module.exports = app;
```

and my `index.js`:

```js
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('index', { title: 'Express' });
});

var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Post = mongoose.model('Post');
var Comment = mongoose.model('Comment');

router.get('/posts', function(req, res, next) {
  Post.find(function(err, posts){
    if(err){ return next(err); }

    res.json(posts);
  });
});

router.post('/posts', function(req, res, next) {
  var post = new Post(req.body);

  post.save(function(err, post){
    if(err){ return next(err); }

    res.json(post);
  });
});

module.exports = router;
```

Nothing has worked yet and I still have the connection refused error, any other idea?

Answer (score 0):

Your mongoose objects should be placed above your express objects.

Please move the following lines:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Post = mongoose.model('Post');
var Comment = mongoose.model('Comment');
```

To the top of your index.js page and you should be fine.