# Cannot Install cURL on Windows 7 (64-bit) Library Issues

Tags: curl, command-line-interface

I am unable to install cURL on Windows 7, 64-bit version. After viewing multiple tutorials, I am told to do the following:

1. Download cURL from website (https://curl.haxx.se/download.html)
2. Create a 'curl' directory at the base of the C drive (C:\curl)
3. Place the **curl.exe** file from download into 'curl' directory (C:\curl\curl.exe)
4. Visit certificate page (http://curl.haxx.se/docs/caextract.html)
5. Download **cacert.pem** file and rename to **curl-ca-bundle.crt**
6. Place **curl-ca-bundle.crt** file into 'curl' directory (C:\curl\curl-ca-bundle.crt)

At this point the file structure should look like this:

```
C:\
    - curl.exe
    - curl-ca-bundle.crt
```

7. Right-click Computer and select 'Properties'
8. Click "Advanced system settings" on the right navigation bar
9. On System Settings window, click "Environment Variables..." button at bottom
10. Under "System Variables" section, click "Path" variable and click "Edit..."
11. At the end of this path, enter ";C:\curl" and click OK
12. Return to Command Prompt and enter your curl command

For myself, I am testing a URL for my Angular Project with both Express and MongoDB installed:

```
curl --data 'title=test&link=http://test.com' http://localhost:3000/posts
```

Regardless of whether my code works or not, the cURL command returns the following error:

```
curl:./.libs/lt-curl.c:233: FATAL: couldn't find curl.
```

Any ideas is to my issue OR an alternative to installing cURL on a Windows 7 64-bit machine?

Comment: Why tag this angularjs?

Comment: @Dr.Avalanche because I am running an Angular.js setup. While I'm sure this is purely a cURL issue, the particular lib call error, may be associated with a problem people attempting to curl Angular see more than others. Not sure so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the answer. It seems you cannot request data from your curl command if it has not been first sanitized (my requests contained ":" and "/"). The data needs to be sanitized first using the "data-urlencode" switch.

For example, if I try to run the following command:

```
curl http://localhost:3000/posts --data 'title=test'
```

There isn't any issue. However, if I try to pass the website that came from the **link** textfield in the form:

```
curl http://localhost:3000/posts --data 'title=test&link=http://test.com'
```

I will receive the following error (in Windows command prompt):

```
'link' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

Even if I tried with just 'dots':

```
curl http://localhost:3000/posts --data 'title=test&link=www.test.com'
```

I will receive the following error (in Windows command prompt):

```
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: 'link=www.test.com'
```

My solution was to curl the following:

```
curl http://localhost:3000/posts --data 'title=test' --data-urlencode 'link=http://www.test.com'
```

And it was curled successfully.

Initial idea provided on this page as the **second answer**:

[Testing REST routes with curl --data, returns 404](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29552228/testing-rest-routes-with-curl-data-returns-404)